# Differing values for d3.scale.pow(0.5) versus d3.scale.sqrt()

Tags: d3.js

I am working through the free d3 course on Udacity.

One of the exercises we are working through is creating a scale based on the square root of the input e.g. the mapping function should look like

```
y = constant * sqrt(x)
```

Since `sqrt(x)` is equivalent to `x^(0.5)`, I thought that the following two pieces of d3.js should provide the same exact mapping:

```
var y1 = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([52070,1380000000]).range([10,50]);

var y2 = d3.scale.pow(0.5).domain([52070,1380000000]).range([10,50]);
```

However, when I map a number between the two ends of the domain, I get different outputs:

> y1(1000000) = 10.836195102634587
>
> y2(1000000) = 10.027477268653174

*Can someone explain what are the flaws in my assumption that the two scales are equivalent?*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the exponent in the wrong place. Set your `pow()` scale defining the `exponent` like this:

```
var y2 = d3.scale.pow().exponent(0.5).domain([52070,1380000000]).range([10,50]);
```

And you'll get the correct values for both scales:

```
console.log(y1(1000000))//returns 10.836195102634587
console.log(y2(1000000))//returns 10.836195102634587
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var y1 = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([52070,1380000000]).range([10,50]);

var y2 = d3.scale.pow().exponent(0.5).domain([52070,1380000000]).range([10,50]);

console.log(y1(1000000))
console.log(y2(1000000))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation:**

You shouldn't put any value inside the parenthesis of `pow()`. You can put values here, but they won't have any effect. So, when you do:

```
var y2 = d3.scale.pow(0.5).domain([52070,1380000000]).range([10,50]);
```

That's the same of:

```
var y2 = d3.scale.pow().domain([52070,1380000000]).range([10,50]);
```

Which has no `exponent`, and uses the default value of `1`. Thus, the two previous lines are the same of:

```
var y2 = d3.scale.pow().exponent(1).domain([52070,1380000000]).range([10,50]);
```

Here is another snippet to proof it:

```js
var test1 = d3.scale.pow(0.5).domain([52070,1380000000]).range([10,50]);
var test2 = d3.scale.pow().domain([52070,1380000000]).range([10,50]);
var test3 = d3.scale.pow().exponent(1).domain([52070,1380000000]).range([10,50]);

console.log(test1(1000000));
console.log(test2(1000000));
console.log(test3(1000000));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```